# CSS center element which parent is larger then screen

Tags: css, center

This is my html:

```
<div id="bar">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="item"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

#bar is 100% and overflow hidden.

.container is 1600px with margin: 0 auto; to center it. Also position:relative;

.item is 960px and I want to center this element

When my screen is exactly 1600px, .item is centered correctly. But when I make it smaller, .item moves more to the right.
It looks like the calculated margin is always 320px ((1600-960)/2) and is calculated relative from .container. But the browser applies the margin relative to the viewport.

Does anyone know how to let the browser apply the margin relative from his parent when the parent is not visible?

Comment: Would margin:0 auto not work on .item as well since the width is defined? Otherwise I'd look into a JS solution.

Comment: I can't understand the problem without knowing the content of .item (and the other divs, if they have other content). Can you please provide a example which demonstrates the problem?

Comment: _When my screen is exactly 1600px, .item is centered correctly. But when I make it smaller, .item moves more to the right._ This is because the DOM is anchored to the left part of the viewport and the overflow only extends beyond the right side. Why are you specifying `1600px`?

Comment: Because bij background-image on .item has a width of 1600px. So on large screens it looks great, but  on screens with a resulution between 1600 and 960 I don't want a horizontal scroll bar.
I know how to fix it with javascript but I'm very curious about a CSS solution. See the jsfiddle(http://jsfiddle.net/bbxgm/) and comment below.

Answer (score 0):

I have come up with an example of this on jsfiddle, but used smaller dimensions so its viewable. Adding `margin: 0 auto;` to .item should fix it.

http://jsfiddle.net/EMHSs/

Comment: maceyj2 I have altered you're jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/bbxgm/ . All the 96px boxes are 'the site'. In the green box i have a large background image, but I don't want a scroll bar when the screen is smaller than 160px; Therefore I put the red box with 100% and overflow hidden.

Comment: yes, that makes no difference. When the screen is smaller, the blue box is not in the center of the viewport anymore...